# function.php (wordpress) - Add class to P if it contains iframe

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code:

```
<p>
<iframe src=""></iframe>
</p>
```

How can I add a class to the P using function.php? only in a single post?

so the result will be:

```
<p class="something">
 <iframe src=""></iframe>
</p>
```

Comment: Describe your Problem. I dont get it.

Comment: i want to add a class to the P using php

Comment: Where does your first block of code live? In the WordPress content editor? Or in a WordPress templates?

Comment: Why in function.php? Do it in the template.

Comment: There's a lot of places that this could be in WordPress. Please be specific where you are adding the iframe. Off the top of my head: functions.php, WYSIWYG editor, Plugin, Head/Footer blocks, Content Blocks etc. We have no idea where this iframe is initially coming from

Comment: check this: https://awr.as/d6r.. all i want is to add a class to the p if this p contains iframe

Comment: That link won't help us, since we have no idea where the PHP is that is rendering that content. Also, why do you want do this using `functions.php`? Are you entering this iFrame in your editor?

Comment: Yes, i add this iFrame in the editor, I want to style it and style the P too. Sorry maybe I didn't clear it up :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't given us much of an explanation of where your HTML is coming, I'll just have to guess at a bunch of things. The code below will output the requested HTML on a single post.

```php
if (get_queried_object_id() === 123) {
    echo '<p class="something"><iframe src=""></iframe></p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your p tag has children using jQuery:

```
// Add some class that is unique or someting
if ( $('p.unique-class').children().length > 0 ) {
     // do something
     $(this).addClass('your-class');
}

// or

if ( $('p.unique-class').find('iframe').length > 0 ) {
    // do something
     $('p.unique-class').addClass('your-class');
}
```